# pod boost install error tar: Unrecognized archive format

Tags: ios, boost, cocoapods

Following [this](https://github.com/cine-io/cineio-broadcast-ios#example-application) link, am trying to create a sample project given in the link.

I created the `pod` file as given in the link but when I install the pod, I get the following error:

```
    [!] Error installing boost
[!] /usr/bin/tar xfz /Volumes/DATA/../cineio-broadcast/Pods/boost/file.tgz -C /Volumes/DATA/../cineio-broadcast/Pods/boost

tar: Unrecognized archive format

tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

Error screenshot is attached below:
[image]

Where am I getting wrong? How do I solve this?

Comment: Search your component in https://cocoapods.org and follow from instructions.

Answer (score 3):

First of all look at source url in boost podspec file: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/boost/1.59.0/boost.podspec.json

It could be unreachable from your network.

Comment: or the .tgz file is unreachable